# semantic-ui-react form method type

Tags: semantic-ui-react

The `semantic-ui-react` library doesn't seem to allow you to set a method on the form element, i.e. `<Form method="POST">`.

I need to send the form data to another site on submit.  I wanted to just use Semantic-UI forms here like I am everywhere else, but I can't seem to set the method.  Is it impossible to do with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just creating your own `onSubmit` function? Like `<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` where handleSubmit is a function you defined that submits an HTTP request?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even think of that.  I think that's definitely the correct approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been always possible, Semantic UI React passes all unhandled props down to the component, see code below:

```
<Form method='POST' /> 
// produces: <form method="POST" class="ui form">

<Form action='/' method='POST' />
// produces: <form method="POST" action="/" class="ui form">
```